# Ajax Portal, portlet to portlet communication

Tags: portlet

After having done lot of research, I have decided to go with the [AjaxPortal](http://code.google.com/p/ajaxportal/) API for my application.

I have one requirement which needs portlet to portlet interaction. Will that be actually possible in any of the portlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are best in business in Portlets.

- [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com)
- [JetSpeed](http://wiki.apache.org/portals/Jetspeed2)
- [Gate In](http://www.jboss.org/gatein/documentation/gateinportal)